# CosmosDB API for Mongo Treats Multikey Unique Indexes Differently to MongoDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm attempting to drop Azure CosmosDB into a project where MongoDB was originally used. I've hit an issue where by unique indexes are being treated differently across CosmosDB and MongoDB, and I can't find any docs that suggest I should see an issue.

To illustrate this, I've used the `mongo` cli to connect to my CosmosDB and my MongoDB (version 3.6) and have run the following commands to create a collection, define some unique multikey indexes, and then insert some documents:

```
# combination of id + study should be unique
db.repro_issue.ensureIndex({"id":1,"study":1},{unique:true})       

# combination of path + study should be unique
db.repro_issue.ensureIndex({"path":1,"study":1},{unique:true})     

# EXPECTED: PASS (first document, so everything in unique)
db.repro_issue.insert({"id":"my_id_1", "path":"path_1", study:1})  

# EXPECTED: PASS (id + study unique, path + study unique)
db.repro_issue.insert({"id":"my_id_2", "path":"path_2", study:1})  

# EXPECTED: FAIL (id + study unique, path + study NOT unique)
db.repro_issue.insert({"id":"my_id_3", "path":"path_2", study:1})  

# EXPECTED: 2 documents returned
db.repro_issue.find()
```

The above works fine against MongoDB 3.6. It generates an error against a CosmosDB instance when the 2nd document is inserted because...

```
globaldb:PRIMARY> db.repro_issue.insert({"id":"my_id_2", "path":"path_2", study:1})
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: opencga_catalog.repro_issue Failed _id or unique key constraint"
    }
})
```

It appears to be checking the `study` is unique, rather than the combination of both `study` with `id` or `study` with `path`.

Is this a known limitation with CosmosDB's API for MongoDB? Or is there something I can do, without code changes, that would give me the expected result?

FYI I've switched on the following two Preview features for CosmosDB:

- Enable "Aggregation Pipeline"
- Enable "MongoDB 3.4 wire protocol (version 5)"

Comment: Have you tried with a single-property key? Cosmos DB's MongoDB API doesn't currently support compound keys.

Comment: Single property keys work fine for me. Do you have any docs or references that confirm this limitation in CosmosDB?